# Do I need different content types for correlated items

Tags: nodes

I have different types of correlated content items like news, articles, ebooks and books. Some items have same fields, for example news and articles, but some have different fields.

Do I make different content types, or just manage that with different vocabularies?

Comment: This is an old discussion covered thoroughly in many sites, for instance https://drupal.org/node/62956

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends on your later plans with those content entities and how your editors will be using the system, I guess it will be easier for them to create a new "news" article if there's an actual create news link, instead of having a "somewhat" containing all of the information holding magic content type called "content".

You can reuse fields you created on another content type, so you will not create countless fields for the same type of content across multiple content types. (each field will be a at least 2 tables in your database - [more](https://drupal.org/node/1577260)).

- news

  - title (default)
  - body (default, can be reused)
  - source (can be reused)
- articles

  - title
  - body
  - source
- ebook

  - title
  - body
  - source
  - author
  - downloadlink

If you plan to theme these entries differently you will almost always want to create a own content type for them, so you can have multiple templates, panel panes or what-else you are going to use. Just so you don't get me wrong: you can create different templates for a node based on it's related taxonomy term, but this will require additional code while there are default template suggestions for content types already, also dealing with content types in views is probably easier than having the same content type and variants created by taxonomy term.